# What is the best way to embed jetty in a war file?

Tags: maven, jetty

I'm trying to embed jetty in a war file so I can launch it frcom the command line, but I'm struggling.  I'm using maven, has anyone done this before?

Thanks! Steph

Comment: did you read this ? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin and why are you struggling ?

Comment: yep.  I think it's a combination of which J2EE jars I need.  It's very finicky.

Comment: There's a difference between writing an application that uses an embedded Jetty to run a web server, and using the maven-jetty-plugin to execute an arbitrary web application from maven.  Which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you already did this, but as far as I remember, you need to copy all dependencies that are *provided* in your war file as direct dependencies of the jetty plugin.

Providing more details about your current architecture and issues may help...